# Parameters in parentheses after a method name: what are they and what do they do?

Tags: c#, oop

Newb to C# and OOP.  My journey thus far has been to take code bases that I've inherited from former developers and either address issues, or add enhancements, whilst trying to understand said code bases' structures from front-to-back.

I'm having trouble fully grasping the concept around the parameters which follow the initial declaration of a method.  Here's an example of a method I'm working with:

```
public List<Entity> ParseCsvFile(List<string> entries, string urlFile)
    {
      entries.RemoveAt(entries.Count - 1);
      entries.RemoveAt(0);
      List<Entity> entities = new List<Entity>();

      foreach (string line in entries)
      {
        Entity entityManagement = new Entity();
        string[] lineParts = line.Split('|');
        entityManagement.Identifier = lineParts[0];
        entityManagement.ProductId = 1234;
        entityManagement.Category = "ABCDE";
        entities.Add(entityManagement);
      }
      return entities;
    }
```

The part after `ParseCsvFile` in parentheses: `(List<string> entries, string urlFile)`
Could someone explain what these are and what they do, perhaps with metaphors/analogies/real-world examples?

Comment: Obviously, these are method parameters

Comment: [Method parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters) you should read the docs

Comment: This is basic question and the answer you can find by reading [programing language basics tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)

Comment: Better link to docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#method-parameters-vs-arguments

Comment: An analogy in real world would be say CreateOrder method but you would need to provide payment details and product number. In the real world you would hand the staff the product(s) and your credit card

Comment: @Stpete111 Read this book: [Beginning Microsoft Visual C# 2012](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Visual-C-2012-Programming.productCd-1118314417.html)

Comment: `List<string> entries` seems to be a list of rows from a CSV file. The function splits up each row, creates a model object and fills it with the data found in the row.  `string urlFile` seems to be some left-over. If you shortened that code, it may be in use but as is, it doesn't seem to be used. Maybe it's the filename/path for logging /debugging purposes or the File I/O has been done inside in an earlier version of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to see their purpose if you look at a simpler function for example:

```
public int Add(int number1, int number2)
{
    return number1 + number 2;
}
```

Above there is a function that adds two numbers together and returns the result. It is a set of instructions to follow. How can it follow the instructions if it doesn't know what numbers to use.
That's where calling the function comes in.
for example:

```
var result = Add(2, 5);
```

In this scenario result = 7.

2 is replacing number1 in the function and 5 is replacing number2.

Comment: Thank you, Jack. That makes perfect sense.  All it takes is someone who's willing to help.